# Find the month in which maximum number of employees hired

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a situation where I need to find the month in which maximum number of employees hired.

Here is my Employee table:

[image]

Although I have a solution for this:

```
select MM 
from (
       select *, dense_RANK() OVER(order by cnt desc) as rnk 
       from (
              select month(doj) as MM,count(month(doj)) as CNT 
              from employee 
              group by month(doj)
       )x 
   )y 
   where rnk=1
```

But I am not satisfied with what i have implemented and want the most feasible solution for it.

Comment: @JaydipJ, thanks for formatting my question. As you can see that i am new to stackoverflow and was not sure how helpful formatting is for viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is:

```
select top 1 year(doj), month(doj), count(*)
from employee
group by year(doj), month(doj)
order by count(*) desc;
```

Notes:

- This interprets "month" as being "year/month".  If you really do only want the month, then remove `year()` from both the `select` and `group by`.
- This returns one row.  If you want multiple rows when there are ties, then use `select top (1) with ties`.